# Passing object to component

Tags: reactjs

Can someone please explain to me why the following error happens.

```
export default function Fu(props){
  ...
  const postMarkup = post ? <PostDetail post={post} /> : <p>Loading...</p>;
  return (
    {postMarkup}
  )
}
```

error [image]

but if just if just call the component it loads fine.

```
export default function Fu(props){
  ...
  return (
    <PostDetail post={post} />
  )
}
```

I tried puting the post in an array but that didnt work either. `setPost([data])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
return (
  {postMarkup}
)
```

returns an object, just like:

```
return {postMarkup: postMarkup};
```

Return the plain `postMarkup` React element, and it'll be interpreted correctly:

```
return postMarkup;
```

Your version that works fine works because it *is* returning JSX markup here:

```
<PostDetail post={post} />
```

Comment: postMarkup is jsx so no need to wrap it in jsx simply return postMarkup

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @Moshe Sommers in the comments section, you can just return the component right away.

```
return postMarkup
```

---

As said in the error messages, object is not valid as React child. However, arrays are.

```
return (
  [postMarkup, postMarkup]
)
```

Comment: No need to make it an array just return postMatkup without the curly braces.